# How to prevent users to access wp admin and wp-login.php?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

I want restrict all users to access WordPress website login.

*For example*: Suppose I have WordPress website domain `example1.com` and I want to restrict all users to access admin login with `example1.com/wp-admin` and `example1.com/wp-login.php`.

When any user hits these url it redirect to **restrict_user** page and also I want to access wordpress login page with `example1.com/user_login` instead of hit `example1.com/wp-admin` and `example1.com/wp-login.php` urls.

And please suggest me how can i make my WordPress website more secure from hacking?

Answer (score 2):

## Restricting access to `wp-admin` directory

### Apache 2.4+

Add this snippet to your `.htaccess` file, created in `wp-admin` directory:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ip 64.176.174.0/255.255.255.0
    Require ip 64.176.176.0/255.255.255.0
</RequireAny>
```

and add as many **IP Address/Subnet Mask** pairs, as you wish, regarding the client IP address you would like to have access to admin area. I have added two samples above.

### Apache 2.4-

Add this snippet to your `.htaccess` file, created in `wp-admin` directory:

```
<Directory>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 64.176.174.0/255.255.255.0
</Directory>
```

---

## Restricting access to `wp-login.php` path

Add this snippet to you current theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_checkRole(){
    if( !( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) && !( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'restrict_user' ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_checkRole' );
```

## Changing the `wp-admin` path

It is possible to change it, but why do you think that has any value at all? You cannot hide anything from a Bot - that is just not possible to do.

Hackers use automated Bot programs to find whatever they want to find.

A good approach is **Action Approach**:

> hacker `X` does bad action `Y` and the result is `Z = Forbidden`.

So just use the presented method in **Restricting access to wp-login.php path** section and that will be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much.I implemented to my site.But i have again new question.
a) Now, when i trying to access my site through wp-admin it shows "The page isn't redirecting properly" but i want to redirect that user to my new terms page not shown error page.
b) Can we restrict wp-login.php page from users same as wp-admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can lock down the wp-admin page with htaccess deny all and hen setting an allowed ip.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

You can also set a htpasswd file with allowed logins and password protect the page. I would also make sure your username in wp-admin is not something easy like 'admin' or 'editor'.

```
<IfModule mod_auth.c>
 AuthUserFile /home/path/.htpasswd
 AuthName "Username and password required"
 AuthType Basic
 <Limit GET POST>
  Require valid-user
 </Limit>
</IfModule>
```

Furthermore i would highly recommend wordfence as a good plugin for protection from hacks etc.

Answer (score 0):

From **nginx**, using **php7.0-fpm** on **Ubuntu 16.04LTS**.

My base configuration I modified from:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

I found a bunch of configs online that tried to combine `wp-login.php` and `wp-admin` into the same rule, but allowed `wp-login.php` to be raw downloadable! 
 Granted, its a generic Wordpress file, but that is dangerous behaviour.

I've separated the rules, since `wp-admin` is a folder, anything accessed within will follow generic rules for images/php/etc. For `wp-login.php` I wanted to specifically replicate php execution.  I've allows full internal network access to `10.x.x.x`.

```
  location ~ wp-login\.php {
    allow 10.0.0.0/8
    deny all;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }
  location /wp-admin/ {
    allow 10.0.0.0/8
    deny all;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
```